# Facebook like image viewing

Tags: html, facebook, image, performance, image-processing

I have been wondering how facebook load images so fast.
I am not on any projects related to my question, but I'm just really interested.

With some observation, I noticed that facebook loads a low quality picture as temporary, and shows the high quality one as soon as it is fully loaded.
this makes it seem like it loaded it so fast, but really it was just a low quality one at first.

My question is, how does facebook implement that?
When I put image on my site, it loads it from top to bottom in full quality right on.

Is this done through Javascript/Jquery ajax? or something?
is done through php?

did facebook make to versions on their end? low and high quality? and send the low quality one first?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! you are right, Facbook loads low quality image first then render it based on network speed. this method called "Progressive JPEGs" which is another type of JPEGs, they are rendered, as the name suggests, progressively.

First you see a low quality version of the whole image. Then, as more of the image information arrives over the network, the quality gradually improves.

From usability perspective, progressive is usually good, because the user gets feedback that something is going on. Also if you’re on a slow connection, progressive JPEG is preferable because you don’t need to wait for the whole image to arrive in order to get an idea if it is what you wanted. If not, you can click away from the page or hit the back button, without waiting for the (potentially large) high quality image.

There is controversial information in blogs and books whether progressive JPEGs are bigger or smaller than the baseline JPEGs in terms of file size.

If you use tool like Photoshop or any designing tool while saving any document in jpg or other format it will ask you 2 option one is for Baseline and another one is Progressive.

But you can achieve same on run time also if you have written any API for this to convert your baseline images to Progressive images while displaying on webpage.

Comment: Wow thanks, this really helped a lot.
I was about to ask how do I make such type of JPEGs but you've already answered it too.

Thanks! :D

Comment: @user2128576: that's gr8 that you got the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, when you click on an image from the Facebook UI, the viewer appears with the low thumbnail version (or a slightly larger version of the thumbnail) loaded. Because of browser caching, that low quality image will display very quickly.

Then in the background, they use javascript to load the higher quality image. Then using some javascript events, they can detect when the higher quality image has loaded. Once loaded, replace the lower quality version with the higher quality version of it.

So from the UI perspective, it's only Javascript. When you upload the photo, they create multiple sizes of the image to allow this effect to happen.